# How to fix xampp installation?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm getting this error message when trying to reach phpmyadmin. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Does anyone know how to fix this? I've tried reinstalling, but that hasn't worked.

[image]

Comment: It would have been better to copy-paste the text, instead of an image

Comment: Does the directory `/opt/lampp/temp` (in your screenshot) exist, and is it writable by the webserver?

Comment: does exist, but there's a lock on the folder.
edit: well that answers my question. I changed the permissions of the folder sudo chmod -R ugo+rw and now it works. Do you suggest the permissions should be different? I'm the only one that has access to this computer so I'm not concerned with security.